# <Span> in bottom right corner of <div> without "position:absolute"

Tags: html, css

I want a div looking like this:

```
+--------------------------------+
|                                |
|     "This is a quote..."       |
|                                |
|                         Author |   
+--------------------------------+
```

I can't position the author's name in the bottom right corner. I want to know how to do it without using `position:absolute` and my div does not have a fixed size.

```css
.quote {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: white;
}

.author {
  color: red;
  float: right bottom; /* does not work ... it works if I remove 'bottom' but I don't like it because I want a vertical space between the quote and the author*/
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <span class="author">loremipsum.io</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your div doesn't need a fixed size to use position:absolute on the span. Also, there is no float bottom, nor does float accept two values.

Comment: if I use position:absolute on the span it is positionned at the bottom right of the screen

Comment: Yup. That's because positioning something absolutely is relative to its closest positioned ancestor. In other words, just put a relative position on the div and voila, it works (without the float at all, and setting the bottom and right properties on the span instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do here.  You could use flexbox and set the span to `align-self: flex-end` like so:

```css
.quote{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:5px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.quote span{
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <span class="author">loremipsum.io</span>
</div>
```

or you can just right align text in your span and set the span to `display:block` like so:

```css
.quote{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:5px;
}

.quote span{
  display:block;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <span class="author">loremipsum.io</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, using absolute positioning is file if you use `position: relative` within the `quote` class.

Another approach could be achieved with CSS Grid like so:

```html
<div class="quote">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  <span class="author">loremipsum.io</span>
</div>
```

```css
.quote {
  display: grid;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.quote .author {
  justify-self: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine works no matter what height the container is.

```css
.quote {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.quote p {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.quote span {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <span class="author">loremipsum.io</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using absolute positioning in this case. It doesn't matter if the parent div, `.quote`, has a fixed size, the only requirement is that you set `position: relative` on the parent.

One caveat with absolute positioning is that it could overlap other content, so adding a padding value to the parent `div` large enough to "make room" for the absolutely positioned text is recommended.